# sshj: how to read InputStream from long-running command while command is executing

Tags: java, sshj

Currently I am executing command over ssh using:

```
val sshCmd = session.exec(command)
println(IOUtils.readFully(sshCmd.inputStream).toString())
sshCmd.join()
```

However, to see the output I need to *wait* until the command is finished.

How can I get "live" response?

I guess I can read the input stream until end of the line occurs and then print the line; however, is there already some method in the library that can help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It blocks and waits for the whole thing because that's what `IOUtils.readFully` is meant to do, it reads *fully*.
Instead, to read line-by-line, you can do something as simple as:

```
 try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sshCmd.inputStream))) {
     String line;
     while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(line);
     }
 } catch (IOException e) {
     System.out.println(e);
 }
```